# How to format data in the column having different type in python?

Tags: python

I have a DataFrame Named 'App rating" in which there is a column 'Size' containing values Like '2.3M' , '924k' and 'Varies with devices'. How to format data in same format ? i mean to say how to convert 'Mb' to 'Kb' ? so that i can do my further analysis.

[image]

Comment: have a list of those values, then read each value in a loop and if any of the current value consists of 'M' then divide that value by 10^3 to convert to 'K' and do vice versa to convert from "k" to "m".

Comment: i have tired with this:   

def func(s):
    if 'K' in s:
        return float(s.replace('K',''))/1000
    else : return float(s.replace('M',''))

gp['Size'] = app_size.apply(func)

I am getting this error:


TypeError: ("cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>", 'occurred at index Size')